# Jquery plugin uploadify not working on ie

Tags: jquery, flash

I've setup jquery's uploadify plugin on my server, at this address:
http://s284590825.onlinehome.us/example/

The problem is: The browse button is missing when I use IE8.

On FF and Safari I can see the "browse" button.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

UPDATE:

Having read the comments below, I just visited http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15507.html to find out my flash version. It turns out my flash version was different from the current version. Now the plug-in is working just fine.

Comment: @Elliott: you see the button but the uploadify couldn't proccessing file upload

Answer (score 0):

I can see it here in IE8. Try Ctrl-F5 maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's working under IE8, maybe you should delete your cache or something.

Btw, Nice plug-in tho.

Answer (score 0):

install a flash player in IE

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be a comment if anything.